# Is there an equivalent of DSE's Nodesync in open-source Apache Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

Is there any equivalent tool in Apache cassandra(Open source) for continuous background repair process same as of datastax Cassandra nodesync.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: You can check http://cassandra-reaper.io/

Comment: Thanks a lot.Will test the performance

Answer (score 0):

The [Nodesync service](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.8/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/config/configNodesyncTOC.html) is an enterprise feature that is only available in [DataStax Enterprise](https://www.datastax.com/products/datastax-enterprise) and doesn't have an open-source equivalent since it
uses a different mechanism to the traditional anti-entropy repairs (does not use `nodetool repair`).

The closest you can get is the open-source tool [Cassandra Reaper](http://cassandra-reaper.io/docs/) which automates repairs by splitting the repair jobs into small segments (token ranges) and Reaper puts these segments into a schedule to get repaired periodically. Cheers!